# API Controller returns corrupted data

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I am currently working on a Blazor Webassembly App and am struggling with my API-Controller.
In the get method of my API controller (see below), I am trying to join the objects using Linq.

When I try to fetch the data with the API call, in exactly every second object the properties TypeId and Type (sometimes even the Status) are null.
TypeId can be null, but in this query there is a TypeId in every object.

On calling the API, Visual Studio shows me the associated SQL request in the output window.
When I copy/paste this request to SSMS, I get the correct data with joins, as expected.

If I comment the two includes in the get method, all objects have a TypeId.
The method to fetch single objects works fine.

Models:

```
    public partial class Surety
    {
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public int? TypeId { get; set; }
        public int StatusId { get; set; }
        ...
        public SuretyStatus Status { get; set; } = null!;
        public SuretyType? Type { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class SuretyType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; } = null!;
    }

    public partial class SuretyStatus
    {
        public int Id { get; set; } 
        public string? Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Model-Creating in Db-Context:

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Surety>(entity =>
            {
                entity.HasKey(e => e.Number);

                entity.Property(e => e.Number).ValueGeneratedNever();

                entity.HasOne(s => s.Status)
                    .WithOne()
                    .HasForeignKey<Surety>(d => d.StatusId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Sureties_SuretyStatus");

                entity.HasOne(d => d.Type)
                    .WithOne()
                    .HasForeignKey<Surety>(d => d.TypeId)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Sureties_SuretyType");
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<SuretyStatus>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("SuretyStatus");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

                entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasMaxLength(30);
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<SuretyType>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("SuretyType");

                entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();

                entity.Property(e => e.Name).HasMaxLength(30);
            });

            OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
        }
```

Api-Controller:

```
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Surety>>> GetSureties()
        {
            if (_context.Sureties == null)
                return NotFound();

            return await _context.Sureties
                .Include(s => s.Type)
                .Include(s => s.Status)
                .ToListAsync();
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Surety>> GetSuretyById(int id)
        {
            if (_context.Sureties == null)
                return NotFound();

            var surety = await _context.Sureties
                .Include(s => s.Type)
                .Include(s => s.Status)
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(s => s.Number == id);

            if (surety == null)
                return NotFound();

            return surety;
        }
```

Extract from JSON of the API-response.

```
   {
      "number":1001,
      "typeId":null,
      "statusId":3,
      "status":null,
      "type":null
   },
   {
      "number":1002,
      "status":{
         "id":3,
         "name":"name"
      },
      "type":{
         "id":1,
         "name":"name",
      }
   },
   {
      "number":1003,
      "typeId":null,
      "statusId":3,
      "status":{
         "id":3,
         "name":"name"
      },
      "type":null
   },
   {
      "number":1004,
      "typeId":1,
      "statusId":3,
      "status":{
         "id":3,
         "name":"name"
      },
      "type":{
         "id":1,
         "name":"name",
      }
   },
   {
      "number":1005,
      "typeId":null,
      "statusId":3,
      "status":{
         "id":3,
         "name":"name"
      },
      "type":null
   },
   {
      "number":1006,
      "typeId":1,
      "statusId":3,
      "status":{
         "id":3,
         "name":"name"
      },
      "type":{
         "id":1,
         "name":"name",
      }
   },
   {
      "number":1007,
      "typeId":null,
      "statusId":3,
      "status":{
         "id":3,
         "name":"name"
      },
      "type":null
   },
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong and why the API response is missing data in every other record?

Comment: This is indeed very weird. Do you have a [mcve], including a reference database? This could be a bug, or something else. I don't see anything wrong with the code at a quick glance.

Comment: And what is this?? `public SuretyStatus Status { get; set; } = null!;` <- looks very evil!

Comment: if exists json settings, can you share? and when you ef core debugging, is data correct?

Comment: Maybe it's just a personalism but rather than using lambda for foreign keys, I write them as strings with the very exact name I have on the db, plus I never use the `.HasConstraintName()` to map the FK relationship. Try removing them and see what happens

Comment: @JHBonarius I had VStudio create the DB context and models based on my database. 
= null! looks evil, but it is the null-forgiving operator that is automatically used when creating the scaffold dbcontext.

Comment: @OkanKaradag I have not made any json settings. 
What exactly do you mean by EF Core debugging?
When I get the data from the controller using the linq expression, it is immediately wrong.

Comment: @StefanoBuzzoni Removing .HasConstraintName() did not change anything.
Doesn't seem necessary either though, so I'll leave it out, thanks.

Comment: "...in this query there is a TypeId in every object." How do you know that? Did you try to run the same query with sql and got different results?

Comment: @DimitrisMaragkos Simply because I have checked it.
Yep, even with the request VS gives me when I call the API, I get the correct data.
This is the request I mentioned:
SELECT [s].[Number], [s].[StatusId], [s].[TypeId], [s0].[Id], [s0].[Name], [s1].[Id], [s1].[Name]
FROM [Sureties] AS [s]
LEFT JOIN [SuretyType] AS [s0] ON [s].[TypeId] = [s0].[Id]
INNER JOIN [SuretyStatus] AS [s1] ON [s].[StatusId] = [s1].[Id]

Comment: Wow, that is ugly indeed. It's stating "this property cannot be null, but oh, by the way, I set it to null and you should ignore that."

Comment: Instead of immidiately returning the list save it to a variable e.g. `data` and then do `var test = data.First(x => x.Number == 1001).TypeId;` and check what is the value in the test variable.

Comment: I have already tried that. The values are still the same. Btw, API calls for single objects work fine.  I've added the method to the controller above.